# Magento 2: Why my products aren't showing in Catalog Search?

Tags: magento2, catalog, search, catalogsearch

A fairly fresh installation of Magento 2.1.7. 1.9.3.x database migrated over. Everything was working fine, the search worked, until sometime today when it just stopped. The last thing I remember doing was adding the first new product into the Default attribute set (whereas all the other products use **migrated_normal_product** attribute set. Soon after doing that, search stopped working entirely.

It doesn't find anything, not with SKU, not with the product name. I've tried reindexing and clearing the cache, but to no avail.

Advanced Search can find the products just fine, but not the regular one.

Comment: have you check your product with Main Website is Selected?

Comment: Yes, the main website is selected for all products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these configurations in your product:

**General->Status** = Enabled

**General->Visibility** = Catalog,Search

**Inventory->Qty** > 0

**Inventory->Stock Availability** = In Stock

**Websites** = checking your site

**Catgories** = checking your category.

If it doesn't resolve, you can use this SQL command in your database:

```
update indexer_state set status='invalid' where status ='working'
```

Comment: All products have "Catalog, Search" as their Visibility, yet none of them can be found through the search function.

Comment: I've updated, try to run the SQL.